Alternate product for Perkin condensation of salicylaldehyde
For context, this Wikipedia page talks about Perkin condensation, and also states one line:

Salicylaldehyde converted to coumarin using acetic anhydride with acetate as base

Here is my variation of the mechanism (after base treatment):

Why doesn't this happen? Well the very first thing that came in my mind was the repulsion between the two alkoxide ions. I also suppose that the phenoxide won't be a good nucleophile to the bad electrophilic system of the anhydride.

Do you believe that two alkoxides are going to survive in acetic anhydride? Moreover, the second structure has a built in anhydride. That is why intramolecular acetyl transfer is preferred. –
user55119
Commented 1 hour ago   D

@user55119 I got what you mean mostly, any specific reason why the two alkoxides cannot survive? because both are to exist even while the perkin condensation

What do think NaOH in the presence of excess acetic anhydride would do?

@user55119 maybe you could provide the solution or a bigger context, frankly, I am unable to fully understand what you are trying to make me understand :(
